# How to align widgets in a Row using crossAxisAlignment Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to replicate the AppBar widget as shown in the image below. I tried using `Row` widget and added the required widgets inside it's children and added `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center` in order to align all the widgets in center (horizontally, as it is a Row widget). But I'm unable to achieve the results, getting `A RenderFlex overflowed by 26 pixels on the right.` error, (obviously because it is flowing out of the appBar area).

Required:

[image]

Mine:

[image]

Code:

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
            color: Colors.black,
          )
        ],
        leading: InkWell(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 40,
                width: 40,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: const [
                  Text(
                    "Welcome",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 10,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "John",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          onTap: () { // open drawer },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

If anyone could guide me what I'm doing wrong, I would really appreciate it!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try title

```
Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0.0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                color: Colors.black,
              )
            ],
            title: InkWell(
              onTap: (){},
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 40,
                    height: 40,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10,),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: const [
                      Text(
                        "Welcome",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 10,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "John",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: Container(
          ))
```

with leading

```
leadingWidth: double.infinity,
            leading: InkWell(-------)
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this is happening is that you are using **leading** property, which has width limitation defined by **leadingWidth** properly of AppBar, which is 56.0 by default. You can try setting **leadingWidth** with value **double.infinity** and that would work.

Alternatively you should re-consider using **leading**, as its main purpose is some icon or small widget coming before title.

Comment: thanks for your response, what do you suggest instead of using `leading` to make that exact design in `appBar` ?

Comment: you can try with title please look at my answer @dev1ce

Answer (score 0):

you can replace my source code, please it will work 100%. best of luck!

```
 Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
      elevation: 0.0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      actions: [
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
          color: Colors.black,
        )
      ],
      leading: InkWell(
        child: FittedBox(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 40,
                width: 40,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: const [
                  Text(
                    "Welcome",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 10,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "John",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
```